# gluProject() windows coordinate integer value

Tags: opengl

I am using `gluPoject()` to find the (`winX`, `winY`) pixel coordinate from (`objX`, `objY`, `objZ`) world coordinates, but the problem is that `gluProject()` return the `GLdouble` value of (`winX`, `winY`) whereas pixel coordinates are `int`.

I want to know in which scenario should we take `floor(winX)` or `ceil(winX)` for final pixel coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL uses the window coordinates from [0,width) x [0,height) where (0,0) is the bottom left *corner* of the bottom left pixel. The pixel centers are generally at 0.5, so `floor` will be just fine. As you probably don't need the negative range (which is out of screen anyway), just using the integral part will work as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the problem with this solution is OpenGL pipeline doesn't round off the pixel coordinates according to this function. So if I use this function for deciding the final pixel position for a point it may be a case that I may end up mapping my point to a nearby pixel. For example, my point is (1,2,3) and its (winX, winY) value is (2.3, 3.6). So I will map it to (2,4). But when I pass this point to OpenGL using glBegin(GL_POINTS) API it can map to any of the (2,3) or (2, 4) or (3,3) or (3,4) according to OpenGL own rounding off method. I wanted to know how OpenGL does that.

Comment: @kshitij: What matrices do you use when drawing the point as `GL_POINTS`? You should be aware that wwith a typical `glOrtho(0,w,0,h,...)` setup, you will end up again with pixel centers at 0.5, so you have to add 0.5 to x and y after the floor operation. You should also be aware that using multisampling makes things more complicated.